# Error to comparing contact number with firebase database phone number in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, contacts, android-contacts

```
   **
```

**My app is crush
    Error to comparing contact number with firebase database phone number in android
      ERROR in userlist.add(mUser); in MainActivity:
    [enter image description here][1]**

**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.mohaiminur.com.whatp.MainActivity$LoadContact$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:160)
        at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at
```

Comment: For future questions: 1) please search for the error message first, as NullPointerException are covered quite well in other questions, 2) try to reproduce the problem with less code, as it makes it likely that somebody will help faster. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you for suggestion, I am new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize `userList` anywhere. When you call `userlist.add(mUser);` that gives a `NullPointerException`, since you can't add a user to a non-existing list.

To fix this, create the list before trying to add users to it. For example, in the `onCreate`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    selectUsers = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    showContacts();

    userList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: I have done it & also done in "protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)" method I also replace all "selectUsers" to "userList" but it   does not show contact list in recyleview that have in database

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xXFDceAT  Here I can show name & phone number using Toast  but its not works in adapter if i choose userList nothing found but if choose selectusers then all contact is shown that have in phone

Comment: If the `NullPointerException` is gone after the change I explained in my answer, then it was the right answer for the problem you posted. I recommend opening a new question for the new problem, and I highly recommend following the advice outlined in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there.

Answer (score 0):

Your ArrayList not initialize that's why your app was crashed. First initialize your ArrayList.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
                findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    selectUsers = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    userlist = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    showContacts();
```

}

Comment: Why you commented this line.         //finalUsers.add(mUser);

Comment: Because I was trying to find solution  thats why i put finalUsers.add(mUser); in before "if (name.equals(phone))"  to see that can add the value